# How to save last execution of my command in Windows 10 Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have executed a command on Windows 10 Command Prompt and forgot to use '>' operator to redirect the results to a file. Now the result is too long and I cannot see the whole result even with scrolling up. How can I save the whole result in a file after executing it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can retroactively get that data back since its probably in a screen buffer that overwrites itself when screen fills. You'll need to re-run the command with the > symbol as you've indicated

Comment: Thanks. I was executing a python script that was time consuming (about 12 hours) :(